# DbContext not available

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am developing a we application using web form and database first approach (linq to sql). I have not been able to get the DbContext class. I could not reference it. I have visual studion 2010 service pack 1 and MVC 3 installed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We can't possibly know, since you haven't shown us what you're doing.  Did you generate your Linq to SQL context?  Is it in the same or a referenced assembly?  Are you referencing its namespace?  If the compiler is telling you that there's no referenced `DbContext` class, then there's no referenced `DbContext` class.  That's about all we can tell you based on what you've provided.

Comment: I generated the Linq to SQL context, the namespace System.Data.Entity.DbContext is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DbContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) is a class from Entity Framework. With Linq to SQL you should look for [`DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Thus you are using Database First approach, there should be class inherited from [`DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Search it under `.dbml` file in Solution Explorer. If you have `Northwind.dbml` then generated context class should have name `NorthwindDataContext`.

Comment: Yes I understand that but the namespace System.Data.Entity.DbContext is not available. How do I make it available?

Comment: @Wale: If you understand that, then we don't understand... Why do you *need* `DbContext` to be available?  What are you using Entity Framework for if you're already using Linq to Sql?  Technically you can just add a project reference to `System.Data.Entity`, but you're mixing ORMs here.

Comment: Yeah! I'm new to this I guess I got it all confused. Thanks